# Load default image if particular image is not in repository in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to load image dynamically in report.
name of image comes from database and in expression i'm creating repo path.

```
"repo:/images/"+$F{image_name}
```

But it gives me error if that image is not in repository..
when image is not in repository i want to load some default image instead of error.

How to achieve this??

i tried this but it is not working.

```
new java.io.File("repo:/images"+$F{image_name}).exists()?"repo:/images"+$F{image_name}:"repo:/images/default_image"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a Sciptlet class which returns the image? If the image_name exists return that one, otherwise just return the default image.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm not getting what you want to say.
Will you please explain it.

Comment: Well, first of all you need to know what a Scriptlet class is, if you don't you should take a look to this [link](http://morgb.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/create-java-scriptlets-for-jasper.html). Summarizing is a Java method you call when evaluating a field. This Java method can check if the image exists in your repository and return its path and if it doesn't exist you can just return a path to the default image. Let me know if it is clearer now.